# Docker pull image save path

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I'm looking image save path on local machin after run the docker pull done. I cannot find the image saved/temp location after docker pull is finish or during pulling the image from host.

Can i set the different location instead of default location during docker is pulling or after done. Because Drive c is not enought to download during pull the image from host.

Noted: I'm using Docker for Windows.

Drive "C:" and "D:" space before pull the image from host.
[image]

Create the folder at drive "D:\" instead of using drive "C:\"

[image]

Add "data-root" to config
[image]

Related folders and files are created by docker service after changed the config and restart the service.
[image]

Drive "C:\" space is start decrease when docker pull the image from host.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the screenshot I assume you use Linux containers on Docker for windows?

Comment: Hi Tarun, I download from "https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/". and run it on windows 10 ps.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit-1: Will work on Windows containers**

For changing windows containers data location you need to change the `data-root` of the docker daemon. This can be done through settings window. Click on `Daemon` option in Settings windows and switch from `Basic` to `Advanced` settings. Then change the config like below

```
{
  "data-root": "c:/dockerdata",
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": true
}
```

And the data will now be stored at this new location.

[image: Data location change]

**Original Answer - Will work when you use Linux Containers**

You can change the VM location from Settings of Docker for windows - "Images and volumes VHD location"

[image: Change location]

**Edit-1**

If you need to need to see the VM then you need to launch Hyper-V manager and check the VM details

[image: MobyLinuxVM]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I don't see any downloaded file at there.

Comment: May i know which VM?

Comment: Thanks again. I'm running SQL 2016 container in my windows 10 Pro. And i follow this step "https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows/". In order to run the sql i no need to run any VM on my Hyper-V and i stopped the VM "MobyLinuxVM.vhdx". And vhdx size is only 1.48 GB but downloaded file is 14GB.  The things is i cannot find the downladed the file any where after i run "docker pull xxxx".

Comment: Hi, I'll change the setting and get back the result to you.

Comment: I have this error. **cannot specify both "graph" and "data-root" config file options** . Because i already set the "graph" at config before you reply. Should i remove the "graph" from config setting. Here is current setting {
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": true,
  "graph": "e:\\dockerimages"
}

Comment: yes remove graph it is old option now `data-root` should be used

Comment: I redo everything again. But file is still saving to drive "C:\" when i run the docker pull cmd. Please review my post. I screenshot again.

Comment: If it still doesn't work then it is a bug. You should report it to docker

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I post it at docker forum as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found temporary solution for my issue. I don't see any way to change download path at docker cmd parameter or config. Here is solution for whoever face with same issue.

We need to change the default temp folder path at Environment Variable Settings. I used [setx cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6aus.png) line to change temp folder path and then restart the docker service.

$env:TEMP = "D:\temp"
setx TEMP $env:TEMP /M

$env:TMP = "D:\temp"
setx TMP $env:TMP /M

Temp files are save to new temp folder.

[image]